Option Bytes grayed out in STM32CubeProgrammer for STM32H725 in DFU mode
I am currently working with an STM32H725 microcontroller, and I am encountering an issue when trying to access the Option Bytes (OB) via STM32CubeProgrammer in DFU mode. The OB option is grayed out, and I am unable to modify it.
Could there be specific security features in the STM32H725 that prevent access to OB in DFU mode? Is there any solution to unlock this option?
I tried to bypass this by directly modifying the Option Bytes memory addresses through hexadecimal editing, but I have not found any reliable information on the location of its data
